# Optimizing Code: Netlogo - change patch color

Tags: netlogo, patch

Im currently placing turtles ontop of a raster and im asking them to change the color of the patches near them. However this process is taking too much time and i cant find the reason. The following code shows the main part but it shouldnt work.

```
breed[tradis tradi]
breed[tecnos tecno]

to setup-map

  user-message "Se Borrará el Mapa y Las Distancias Guardadas"
  ca
  resize-world 0 700 0 700

    set mundo gis:load-dataset "D:/Geografico/Lago_Tota_SZH_Raster_Grueso.asc"
  gis:set-transformation [-72.994844704 -72.835891153 5.418413284 5.648012857666661] [0 700 0 700]
  set lago gis:load-dataset "D:/Geografico/Lago_Tota_Raster.asc"

  draw-tota
  draw-lago

  set emptypatches patches with [pcolor <= 50]
  ask emptypatches  [set tota "na"]
  set terrain patches with [pcolor > 50 and pcolor < 60]
  ask terrain [set tota 1]
  set border patches with [tota = 1 and any? neighbors with [tota != 1]]



to go
  cultivate

  tick
end

to cultivate

   ask tecnos [ if ticks > 0 and ticks mod 4 = 0 [ask patches in-radius 4  with [tota = 1]
    [set dano_suelo_promedio mean [dano_suelo] of patches
      set pcolor 42
      set cosecha cosecha + 1
      ]
    ifelse pcolor = 42 [][set recuperar recuperar + 1]
    
  ]
  ]

 ask tradis [ if ticks > 0 and ticks mod 6 = 0 [if patch-here = terreno [ask patches in-radius 4  with [terreno]; falta presentar la coseachas 6-3-3
    [set dano_suelo_promedio mean [dano_suelo] of patches
      set pcolor 42
      set cosecha cosecha + 1
   ]
    ifelse pcolor = 42 [][set recuperar recuperar + 1]
    ]
  ]
  ]

end
```

This is the part that is giving me problems. This specific part takes like 30 minutes to run, which makes no sense. It is working, slowly, as patches change color. The raster itself is big, 700x700 so im trying to find a way to ask the least amount of if else so that it can be as fast as possible.

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To continue on what Charles wrote, if you only want to calculate the mean for the relevant patches and not all the patches, I suggest working with a local variable (using `let`) to define the patches and another local variable to define the mean, since I assume that this mean is the same for all patches chosen by a certain turtle. This means that you now calculate the mean of 49 patches 1 time per tecno instead of calculating the mean of all 1002001 patches 49 times per tecno, which is quite a big difference in scale.

```
   ask tecnos [ 
      if ticks > 0 and ticks mod 4 = 0 [
         let my_patches patches in-radius 4 with [tota = 1]
         let my_mean mean [dano_suelo] of my_patches
         ask my_patches [
            set dano_suelo_promedio my_mean
            set pcolor 42
            set cosecha cosecha + 1
         ] ;end of ask my_patches
         ifelse pcolor = 42 [][set recuperar recuperar + 1]
      ] ;end of if
   ] ;end of ask tecnos
```

Comment: Leirs, thank you so much for making it so clear, ill try to use it before giving the check mark, but this looks great.

Answer (score 2):

One thing that occurs to me is that you are asking each `tecnos` and each `tradis` to calculate the same thing, `mean [dano_suelo] of patches`, which is presumably the same for all of them.  If there are lots of patches, that's lots of calculation.  Could you calculate that mean once at the beginning of the procedure and then make it available to each agent?  Or, is there a subset of patches that each agent is to find the mean of?

Charles

Comment: The patches in- radius 4 of each turtle have slightly different dano that why its for each, however there only 100 turtles I don't know why it would take that much (like 3 hours)

Comment: But your statement looks at the mean of all patches, not just those in radius 4. You are asking the patches in radius 4, but the mean applies to all patches, not just the neighbors.

Comment: AAAAA, of course, i thought i was just asking the ones within range, this changes everything charles. Thank you so much for this clarification